# Connection Pooling with Elastic Beanstalk and Amazon RDS

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, connection-pooling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a Java application on Elastic Beanstalk and I am connecting directly to Amazon's RDS for every request, the response time is very long and I need to reduce this. I recently found out I need to do this through Connection Pooling and that Tomcat is capable of carrying this out. Basically, I need to know the following:

1) is Connection Pooling available for an application on elastic beanstalk?

2) If there is any documentation available for this?

3) If it were available through the Tomcat Server, can I configure tomcat directly and what would that affect any of the functions of Elastic Beanstalk?

thankYouuuuuuu :)

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is not available as service, but Elastic Beanstalk is PAAS, you can use any Java libraries on your instance.

Such as [The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)

Connection pooling will not affect any functions of Elastic Beanstalk.